# Assign Shortcut Key Property by programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a MDI Parent form. In this form I create some shortcut keys for menu bar properties. I want to make this shortcut keys conditional active, means I want to control this keys active or not by code. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this on your parent form:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if(keyData == Keys.Enter && someCondition)
    {
        // Interact with your mdi childs somehow
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

This example captures the Enter key. Also, consider splitting the logic in well defined methods, otherwise you will end up with some really hard to read method.